# Проигрывание музыки в фоне игры Android

Tags: разработка-игр, android, java, canvas

Как добавить музыку на фон в игре, игру пишу без всяких движков, чистый канвас. Добавить обычные звуки я смог, там при столкновении и остальное, а вот что бы в фоне заиграла не пойму как, подскажите пожалуйста как.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.test_cbr); 
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping 
        player.setVolume(100,100); 
        player.start();

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: ты как всегда)) спасибо)

Comment: А как остановить воспроизведение музыки в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте `Thread` или `AsyncTask` - а в нем уже проигрывание музыки.

Comment: Как проигрывать саму музыку?